# No health reports available though features enabled

Tags: performance, central-administration, health-analyzer

How do you enable health reports on a SharePoint 2010 server? Under Central Admin, I go to Monitoring, click View Health Reports, and it says: `A health report is not available for this site. Usage processing may be disabled on this server or the usage data for this site has not been processed yet.`

However, when I go to Monitoring > "Configure usage and health data collection", it says that everything is enabled, including "Enable health data collection." We've been using this server for over 3 months.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alex,

Please verify and check the following sections:

- System Settings > Manage Services on Server

  - Ensure that "Web Analytics Data Processing Service" and "Web Analytics Web Service" is running
- Monitoring > Review Job Definitions

  - Change the service to "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage"
  - Make sure the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing" job is enabled

Once enabled, run the timer job and check the health report again

Comment: We are using SP2016 and found "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing " is disabled by default. Is it by purpose? After enable this timer job I am able to view "Slowest Pages" report